# Apply where condition on 2nd level association in CakePHP 2.5.x

Tags: cakephp, model-associations, cakephp-2.5

I want to add a where clause for my 2nd level association in cakephp. In my understanding this should work but it gives me an error

### Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.email_address' in 'where clause'.

```
$options = array(
    'contain' => array(
        'People',
        'People' => array('User')
    ),
    'conditions'=> array(
        'User.email_address' => 'sample@mail.com'
    ), 
    'recursive' =>1,
);
$query = $this->Organization->find('all', $options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$options = array(
    'contain' => array(
        'People' => array(
            'User' => array(
                'conditions'=> array(
                    'User.email_address' => 'sample@mail.com'
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    //'recursive' =>1,
);
$query = $this->Organization->find('all', $options);
```

Read more:

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations**

Comment: it is working but it gives me the result with left join, like it gives me the results with User null where user not match.